# Topologically non trivial cycles

Tags: differential-geometry

I am studying a Stiefel manifold $X$ which is topologically an $S^3$ bundle over an $S^4$ but is not a product space. I am not able to understand that why is it not the product space $S^3 \times S^4$? The reason that I have read is that the $S^3$ fibre bundle over the $S^4$ is not trivial. There is a non-trivial cycle in $X$ which is a $\mathbb{Z}_2$ torsion 3-cycle which is represented by the $S^3$ fibre. However I cannot appreciate the exact meaning of this statement and hence the reasoning.

$X$ is defined as the intersection of the following two surfaces in $\mathbb{C}^5$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^5y_i^2&=0,\\
\sum_{i=1}^5|y_i|^2&=1.
\end{align}

where $y_i\in \mathbb{C}^5.$

Comment: Might [math.se] be better suited for this math question?